# Assertion Error while using 'cvMatMul'

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix-multiplication

In my code, at certain point i have to multiply 2 matrices and take the result in a 3rd matrix. I'm using `cvMatMul()` for this and getting an assertion failed error.
The part of the code which does the matrix multiplication:

```
CvMat* mulMatTt = cvCreateMat(EigenVector->rows,vi->cols,CV_32FC1);
cvMatMul(vi,EigenVector,mulMatTt);
```

Here, vi has 1 row and 10000 cols and Eigen Vector is a 1x1 square matrix. I believe the error is while allocating the size of the matrix `mulMatTt`. Can someone suggest how i can get this working?

The error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((D.rows == ((flags & CV_GEMM_A_T) == 0 ? A.rows : A.cols)) && (D.cols == ((flags & CV_GEMM_B_T) == 0 ? B.cols : B.rows)) && D.type() == A.type()) in cvGEMM, file C:\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp, line 29 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's a pretty horrible to read assertion. It checks three things (all in the one assertion so we don't know which is wrong). So give the library writers a few minus points there.

The three things it checks are:
1) The number of rows of your results matrix is equal to the number of rows of your first matrix (unless you asked for the first matrix to be transposed before the multiplication, in which case it checks if the rows is equivalent to the columns).
2) The number of columns of your results matrix is equal to the number of columns of your second matrix (again, unless it was transposed as above).
3) That the type of your results matrix is the same as the type of your first matrix.

Basically, this is checking that the matrix D = AB is well formed. I assume that there is another check which makes sure A and B are compatible to be multiplied together (A.cols == B.rows (unless transposed) && A.type ==B.type).

So we are failing to make our results matrix correctly.
I think the line:

```
CvMat* mulMatTt = cvCreateMat(EigenVector->rows,vi->cols,CV_32FC);
```

should be:

```
CvMat* mulMatTt = cvCreateMat(vi->rows, EigenVector->cols,CV_32FC);
```

I assume that the types are correct. Also, just a small nitpick on coding style, the pointer dereference should belong with the variable not the type:

```
CvMat *mulMatTt;
```

or else you might fall in to this trap:

```
CvMat* mulMatTt, identity_matrix;
```

where it looks like identity_matrix is of type CvMat* but in fact is CvMat!

Comment: ...Thanx for the details regarding the Assertion Failed error. That was quite informative...!
But in the code i had tried giving the `mulMatTt` size as `vi->rows` and `EigenVector->cols`, but again was getting the assertion failed error.
And abt the nitpik on coding style...thanx will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: Then is it possible the types of the matrices are incompatible?

Comment: I just re-checked the types of the matrices ... they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In my book if you multiply a 1x10000 matrix by a 1x1 matrix the result is a 1x1 matrix not another 1x10000 matrix. So I think the assertion is complaining that `mulMatTt` is the wrong size for the multiplication. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Yea... i had read that in the documentation and tried giving the size of `mulMatTt` as 1x1...but still it was giving an assertion failed error!

Comment: @cameo If you have `A*B`, then 1) the number of columns in `A` must be the same as the number of rows in `B`, and the resulting matrix has `A`s number of rows and `B`'s number of columns.

Comment: @juanchopanza: i believe u are right. What i really was trying to do is port a matlab code to C,C++. And in the matlab file the code is:
y = A*B; 
where A rows = 1, cols 10000.
B rows 1, cols = 1 and 
y rows =1, cols 10000.
I guess `cvMatMul()` is not the same as the mutiplication in matlab.

Comment: @juanchopanza : i guess it took 'B' as a scalar...!
Also,i am running the matlab code in GNU Octave..!! I have read that there r some differences that exist between Octave and MATLAB...not sure if that is a problem...just thinking aloud.! :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: the result is '1x10000'
Thanx for ur time...will try and figure out what exactly is happening in the matlab code..!!  :)

Comment: @jahhaj: u were not wrong. What u said was right.
'multiply a 1x10000 matrix by a 1x1 matrix the result is a 1x1 matrix'
But still i was getting the same error.